Cocompletion without cocontinuous functors
The forgetful functor from the 2-category $\mathsf{Cats}^{\mathrm{loc.small}}_{\mathrm{cocomp}}$ of locally small cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors to the 2-category $\mathsf{Cats}^{\mathrm{loc.small}}$ of locally small categories admits a left adjoint $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}}$ given by the free cocompletion.
When $\mathcal{C}$ is essentially small, we have $\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}}\cong\mathsf{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$.
In particular, we have an equivalence of categories
$$\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})\overset{\mathrm{eq.}}{\cong}\mathsf{CoContFun}(\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}},\mathcal{D})$$
natural in $\mathcal{C}\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathsf{Cats}^{\mathrm{loc.small}})$ and $\mathcal{D}\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathsf{Cats}^{\mathrm{loc.small}}_{\mathrm{cocomp}})$, giving a cocontinuous functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}}$.
If we replace the 2-category of locally small cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors by just the 2-category of locally small cocomplete categories and all functors between them, do we have a similar result? I.e.:
Question 1. Does the forgetful functor from the 2-category of locally small cocomplete categories and all functors between them to the 2-category of locally small categories admit a (bicategorical) left adjoint?
Question 2. If the answer to Question 1 is "yes" and we do have a left adjoint $\mathcal{C}\mapsto\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{ccp}}$, then we will have a functor $\iota\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{ccp}}$. Will this functor be cocontinuous? Will it be fully faithful? If not, is there a modification of this construction satisfying one or both of these conditions, while keeping a suitable notion of universality among cocomplete categories?
The motivation for this question is that the free cocompletion $\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}}$ of an already cocomplete category $\mathcal{C}$ will not be $\mathcal{C}$ again, which is expected, as the universal property of the free cocompletion postulates that a functor $F$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to a cocomplete category $\mathcal{D}$ will induce a cocontinuous functor $\mathcal{C}_{\mathsf{fccp}}\to\mathcal{D}$, even if $F$ is not cocontinuous itself.
So I wonder if there's an alternative cocompletion construction that would adjoin all colimits to $\mathcal{C}$ and come with a corresponding (hopefully cocontinuous and fully faithful) embedding of $\mathcal{C}$ into it (and then whether there's a nice description of it).

The answer to the question is no, but I think I can add something about the motivation (I might be off-topic though).
To see why the answer is no, simply observe that cocomplete categories aren't closed under (any kind of) limits if you allow arbitrary functors. The silliest example would be to find an empty pullback, e.g. the following $Set_* \to Set \leftarrow \{\emptyset\}$, but there are other more interesting examples.
Let me nonetheless try to adress the motivation : it is indeed true that it sometimes feels silly to freely add colimits when you already have them. However, sometimes it is not so silly, and more to the point, sometimes it is convenient to be able to choose which colimits to "keep", and which to freely add. It turns out, if you allow this flexibility then you can give a construction that, while it does not contradict the "no" from before, makes it possible to recover $C$.
The point is that given a (small - I'll briefly adress this restriction in a second) category $C$ and a collection $U$ of cocone diagrams in $C$ (for example, this can be a collection of colimit diagrams, the collection of all colimit diagrams of a given shape, etc.), there is a free category $P_U(C)$ on $C$ which is universal among cocomplete categories receiving a map from $C$, sending all of $U$ to colimit diagrams.
Example : Let $C = O(X)$ be the category of opens of a topological space $X$, and $U$ the collection of cocone diagrams that are dual to the limit diagrams appearing in the definition of "sheaf on $X$". Then $P_U(C) = Sh(X)$.
Now in general, $C\to P_U(C)$ need not be fully faithful. But there is a description of $P_U(C)$ that allows you to say when it is :
Lemma : $P_U(C)$ is equivalent to the full subcategory of $Psh(C) = Fun(C^{op}, Set)$ spanned by the presheaves $F$ that send all diagrams in $U$ to limit diagrams (there is an op, hence limit)
Corollary : If all the diagrams in $U$ are colimit diagrams, then $C \to P_U(C)$ is fully faithful.
In the large case, things are a bit more complicated, but can be made to work under accessibility conditions if you don't freely add too many colimits, so if $U$ is large enough (e.g. $C$ is accessible and $U$ contains all $\kappa$-filtered diagrams for $\kappa$ large enough)

Thank you so much, Maxime! This construction is exactly what I was looking for :)

Cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors don’t have all limits in the 1-categorical sense either, so that’s not quite the issue, is it? We’re looking for a 2-adjunction and it’s something like the PIE limits one wants. I was having trouble seeing whether cocomplete categories are closed under I and E, though I suspect not…

@KevinCarlson I did say "any kind of limits", by which I meant 1-, pseudo, 2-, etc. My example fails as an ordinary and a 2-limit so it takes care of any interpretation

@MaximeRamzi Ah, I figured you meant "any kind of 1-limit". That's a cool observation that one of the commas of that cospan, as well as its pseudo-pullback, are both empty!
